# How can I make a pod use a specific GPU from a k8s node?

Tags: kubernetes, multi-gpu

How can I configure the pod to use a specific model of GPU from the two different GPU models available on my node?

I used gpu-operator to install the drivers, but it can only allocate pods based on the number of GPUs. However, I want to allocate pods based on a specific model of GPU.
Ex: my machine has both RTX 3080 and RTX 3080 Ti. I want the pod to use the RTX 3080 Ti.

Comment: Please red the Kubernetes tag description; `KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here`

Comment: Pretty sure that tags means "configuration and deployment" of the kubernetes cluster itself... otherwise you might as well just say "no one is allowed to discuss kubernetes on SO" since "configuration and deployment" is pretty much entirely what you do when you  develop for kubernetes

Comment: I would interpret this in spirit of "how code running inside pod will be able to access specific GPU"